# Cordova Phonegap Camera getpicture not working on BlackBerry with DATA_URL option

Tags: cordova, blackberry, camera

I have a blackberry APP using the camera feature.

The code base comes from the "sample app" provided within PhoneGap 2.3.0

The index HTML has the line added

```
  <input type="button" value="Take Picture" onclick="app.takePhoto();" />
```

The index.js has the functions added:

```
takePhoto: function(){
    navigator.camera.getPicture(this.cameraSuccess, 
                                this.cameraError, 
                                {   quality: 50, 
                                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL
                                } );
},
cameraSuccess: function(imageData){
    console.log(imageData);
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
},
cameraError: function(){
    alert("error!");
}
```

If I run the Ripple Simulator, the error console in chrome reads:

```
Received Event: deviceready cordova-2.3.0.js:8165
Received Event: deviceready ripple.js:39
blob:http%3A//localhost/1b218c8e-6902-4780-a652-8f7f4d52fe28 cordova-2.3.0.js:8165
blob:http%3A//localhost/1b218c8e-6902-4780-a652-8f7f4d52fe28 ripple.js:39
GET data:image/jpeg;base64,blob:http%3A//localhost/1b218c8e-6902-4780-a652-8f7f4d52fe28
```

If I run the simulator, after adding an image as a camera data I get an Error pop up the error log reads:

```
1:01:16.054: cordovaExample [2013-01-14 18:55:03.858]: Error in error callback: Camera1387674010 = ReferenceError: Can't find variable: imageData
```

When I run on a device, I don't actually know how to read the error output.

Based on what I've shown, why might it be the case that my Phone Gap application isn't taking a photo on the blackberry device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Phonegap **DestinationType.DATA_URL** option don't work well on some BB devices, mostly newer ones. Because modern phones (like BB 9800) have a better camera they also produce a larger pictures, thus converting them to BASE64 string can cause memory problems and empty imageData variable.

You can test this by lowering **targetWidth** and **targetHeight**. If it works on lower resolutions then this is your problem.

It can be solved by using **FILE_URI** instead of **DATA_URL**. But you should try it either way.

In case **FILE_URI** is not working then problem is in BB camera.